# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'capacitor.config.json' in 'node_modules\@codetrix-studio\capacitor-google-auth\dist\esm'

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, capacitor

This is happening because I changed the **capacitor.congfig.json** to **capacitor.congfig.ts**:

```
npm i @codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth
```

for **capacitor angular**

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the dependency directly from Github repo (instead of the npm repo), where it seems to be a greater version (3.1.0 at Github > 3.0.2 at NPM):

```
"@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth": "git://github.com:CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth.git"
```

Here it's author response: https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth/issues/119#issuecomment-974704558

**EDIT:**

If you get an error about missing `capacitor.config.json` and you already have a `capacitor.config.ts` in your root directory, clarify that the missing or error one is the file inside the app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to add capacitor.congfig.json as well as capacitor.congfig.ts to make it work. It is temporary I guess only for this plugin atm.